# Windows cmd FORFILES not working in batch file,but works in command prompt

Tags: batch-file

In the below batch script the line with command FORFILES is not working.
The same statement works fine when it is run separately from a different batch file or from command prompt.
All other statements in the script works fine. 
I have gone through all solutions for similar problems.

```
@echo off
setlocal

SET vFileShare=C:\Users\asande\task\
SET archiveFileList=ArchiveFilesList.txt
SET archFileTimestamp=%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%
rem SET archFileName=%fSignature%%archFileTimestamp%
SET archiveFolder=C:\Users\asande\task\archives\
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\7-Zip

FORFILES /P %archiveFolder% /M *.zip /C "cmd /c del @file" /d -1

IF EXIST %vFileShare%%archiveFileList%. (
            cd %vFileShare%
            7z a -tzip %archiveFolder%%archFileTimestamp%.zip @ArchiveFilesList.txt
) ELSE (
     ECHO %archiveFileList% missing.>>%vFileShare%\Polaris_DatedConversionRate.log.
 )


endlocal

GOTO: EOF
```

Comment: And when you comment out the `@echo off` line, what do you see?

Answer (score 3):

Got the answer, the problem actually is due to following 2 statements

**SET PATH**=C:\Program Files\7-Zip

**FORFILES** /P %archiveFolder% /M *.zip /C "cmd /c del @file" /d -1

**SET PATH** ...... statement should be after **FORFILES** command .
**FORFILES** command will not work even in command prompt if you set **PATH** to some value
before running **FORFILES**. 
(it throws FORFILES is not recognized as an internal or external command.)

Can anyone enhance the answer why PATH does so. And i think it effects some other commands like this.

Comment: `%path%` is a systemvariable, set and used by windows. Don't touch it. Use another name, for example `mypath`

Comment: You can fiddle with the Path in a batch file.  It's fine.  It only changes the path within the context of that batch file.  The problem is that you're completely removing everything already in the path by setting the path that way. You want `set Path=%Path%;C:\Program Files\7-zip` instead.

Comment: And the reason that FORFILES is not working anymore after you change the `PATH` is that it is an executable and not an internal command. So it simply can't find it anymore. Instead of calling just `FORFILES` you could also call `C:\Windows\System32\forfiles.exe` followed by the rest of your line.

Answer (score 0):

`@file` is just the file name. Your working directory is probably different from `%archiveFolder%`, so `del` doesn't find the files it's supposed to delete, because it's looking in the wrong place (`%CD%` instead of `%archiveFolder%`). Try using `@path` instead:

```
forfiles /p "%archiveFolder%" /m *.zip /d -1 /c "%comspec% /c del @path"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SET archiveFolder=C:\Program Files\7-Zip
FORFILES /P %archiveFolder% /M *.zip /C "cmd /c del @file" /d -1
```